# Refactoring Resource spec, want to group different roles (rspec-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I really hope you could help me refactor this:

```
context "a deactivated resource" do
    before(:each)
        @resource = FactoryGirl.create(:deactivatedresource)
    end
    it "does not show in the search (as registred User)" do
        as_user # does the log in 
        visit path_to_search_page
        page.should_not have_content @resource.name
    end
    it "is visible to the resource owner" do
        as_resource_owner(@resource) 
        visit path_to_search_page
        page.should_have content @resource.name         
    end
    it "as unregistred user" do
        as_unregistred_user  # checks for log out and logs out if necessary
        visit path_to_search_page
        page.should_not have_content @resource.name         
    end
```

I would really like to put the `visit`and `should(not) have` part in en extra `after(:each)` block, but this makes a nasty output.
How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see much point to refactoring. Nevertheless you can extract your path and content to instance variables in before filter (or let) to have control from one place. Also, i don`t like your descriptions of specs - make it more readable and write them in one style.